# Show message if no orders in woocommerce

Tags: function, woocommerce, hook, message, orders

I would like to display a message in my-account if the customer has no orders I would like to show "No orders currently".
I guessing there's a function I could use to hook into this somewhere?
Had a good search and cant find anything to get me started.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied my-orders.php to local folder and added an else clause:

```
else{
    echo "No orders";
    }
```

This can be styled using WC css

Answer (score 0):

Modifying from [this tutorial](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/) I think this would work:

```
function wc_get_customer_orders() {

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );

    $customer = wp_get_current_user();

    // Text for our message
    $notice_text = sprintf( 'Hey %1$s &#x1f600; We noticed you haven\'t placed any orders with us.', $customer->display_name );

    // Display our notice if the customer has no orders
    if ( count( $customer_orders ) == 0 ) {
        wc_print_notice( $notice_text, 'notice' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'wc_get_customer_orders' );
```

Basically, on the account page we query for a single order by the currently logged in user. If we don't get an order back we show the notice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've seen that example and tried it. It does work on my account, however I am designing a tabbed dashboard for my account and want the no orders message to appear on the orders page if there are no orders.

Comment: So then just use a different hook from `woocommerce_before_my_account`. Or add that hook to your other tabbed pages.

Comment: Thanks. I'm incuding my-orders.php which is pulling through ok. I've tried the following hooks already: woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions, woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query, woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title, but the function / message doesn't show. i think the problem may be as this is an external / custom page and not a wp page. Is there a way I can include this function as part of an if / else statement or before the include? thanks, :)

Comment: You can run `wc_get_customer_orders()` wherever, even calling it directly I think. But why would you use external pages instead of WP pages?

Comment: Probably be easier to explain if you see my site. it's thecookerytutor dot co .uk. If you register an account or contact me direct via contact page I can show you what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks.